# Symfony 4 - How to make subdomain for route?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, subdomain, host

in my symfony 4 project there are routes for which I would like a base URL different from the others.

For example, for some URLs, it will follow this plan:

**https://myApp.com/[route]**

But for other routes, I would like something like:

**https://app.myApp.com/[route]**

I looked at the doc and I saw that it was necessary to use the "host" in the annotations.

Currently I'm developing locally so my URLs look like

**127.0.0.1:8000/[route]**

So, for a route, by example, I have

```php
    /**
     * Affiche la page de profil de l'utilisateur.
     *
     * @Route("/profile", name="account_profile", host="app.127.0.0.1")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function profile(Request $request)
    { // ... }
```

And it doesn't work, no url found here.

Comment: That's not a valid host. For the annotation to work, the host needs to be valid, and the application needs to be reachable at that host.

Comment: So the application must be in production ?

Answer (score -1):

In your hosts file add

> 127.0.0.1 app.localhost

Restart your server.

In your controller use "app.localhost" for your host variable. As yivi said, it is currently invalid.

If you're going to use both "app.localhost/profile" and "localhost/profile" make sure to give them different names.

I'd recommend using virtual hosts. Some extra configuration might be required.